# How to read AWS cognito custom attributes and logged in user in lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have created a custom attributes inside aws congnito pool, now adding Post authentication lambda and inside of lambda want to read "custom attributes" and loggedin username .

Inside Node.js lambda :

```
  var email=event.request.userAttributes.email;
  var refNumber=event.request.userAttributes.ref_number; //custom attribute
  var loginid=event.request.userAttributes.username;//loggedin id in cognito
```

i am able to fetch email id properly however both loggedin username and custom attribute coming undefined .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The custom attributes are named `custom:xxx` where `xxx` is your custom attribute name:

```
{
    "version": "1",
    ...,
    "userName": "...",
    "triggerSource": "PostAuthentication_Authentication",
    "request": {
        "userAttributes": {
            "sub": "...",
            "cognito:user_status": "CONFIRMED",
            ...
            "locale": "en",
            ...
            "custom:xxx": "yyy"
        },
        "newDeviceUsed": true
    },
    "response": {}
}
```

So for your `ref_number`, it should be `event.request.userAttributes['custom:ref_number']`.

The username is simply `event.userName`.

Comment: Thanks Jogold ,event.request.userAttributes['custom:ref_number'] is working however i am looking logedin username also .

Comment: It's `event.userName`. Updated the answer.